# Side by side data comparison by year in SQL with Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, parameters, comparison, pivot

I need to make a side by side comparison of data by year.

I'm using Microsoft Access 2013.

What I want to obtain is a table like this:

```
╔══════╦══════════╦ ... ╦═══════╦═══════════════╦══════════════╦════════════╗
║ Zone ║ Customer ║ ... ║ Month ║ Previous year ║ Current year ║ Difference ║
╠══════╬══════════╬ ... ╬═══════╬═══════════════╬══════════════╬════════════╣
║ PD   ║ A        ║ ... ║     1 ║ 100€          ║ 150€         ║ +50€       ║
║ PD   ║ B        ║ ... ║     2 ║ 150€          ║ 100€         ║ -50€       ║
║ PD   ║ C        ║ ... ║     1 ║ 200€          ║ 0€           ║ -200€      ║
║ PD   ║ D        ║ ... ║     2 ║ 0€            ║ 100€         ║ +100€      ║
╚══════╩══════════╩ ... ╩═══════╩═══════════════╩══════════════╩════════════╝

("..." stands for other columns)
```

Establishing that the previous year is 2014 and the current is 2015, with this table I can see if:

- a 2014 customer has purchased **more** in 2015 (customer A);
- a 2014 customer has purchased **less** in 2015 (customer B);
- a 2014 customer **has not yet purchased** in 2015 (customer C);
- there's a **new customer** of 2015 (customer D).

When I have a "old" (2014) customer that is not purchasing in 2015 **I need to see that row with a "0€" value** in the Current year column (2015) and so the same for a new customer of 2015 that obviously didn't purchased nothing in 2014.

These are my tables:

- CUSTOMERS (id, company_name, id_zone, id_customer_category)
- CUSTOMER_CATEGORIES (id, description)
- ORDERS (id, id_customer, date, qty, amount (€), id_product_category,
  id_import)
- PRODUCT_CATEGORIES (id, supplier, description)
- ZONES (id, city)
- IMPORTS (id, year, month, supplier)

I created a view (**V_YEAR_SALES**):

```
SELECT Z.ID AS ID_ZONE, Z.CITY, C.COMPANY_NAME AS CUSTOMER, CAT.DESCRIPTION AS CUSTOMER_CATEGORY, P.SUPPLIER, P.DESCRIPTION AS PRODUCT_CATEGORY, I.MONTH, I.YEAR, SUM(O.AMOUNT) AS AMOUNT
FROM ((((ORDERS AS O 
    INNER JOIN CUSTOMERS AS C ON O.ID_CUSTOMER = C.ID) 
    INNER JOIN ZONES AS Z ON Z.ID = C.ID_ZONE) 
    INNER JOIN IMPORTS AS I ON I.ID = O.ID_IMPORT) 
    INNER JOIN CUSTOMER_CATEGORIES AS CAT ON CAT.ID = C.ID_CUSTOMER_CATEGORY)
    INNER JOIN PRODUCT_CATEGORIES AS P ON O.ID_PRODUCT_CATEGORY = P.ID
GROUP BY Z.ID, Z.CITY, C.COMPANY_NAME, CAT.DESCRIPTION, P.SUPPLIER, P.DESCRIPTION, I.MONTH, I.YEAR
ORDER BY Z.CITY, P.SUPPLIER, P.DESCRIPTION, CAT.DESCRIPTION, C.COMPANY_NAME, I.YEAR, I.MONTH;
```

Everytime I need to make a comparison between a year and the previous I use this view (**V_SALES_COMPARISON**) passing the year:

```
SELECT S1.ID_ZONE, S1.CITY, S1.ID_CUSTOMER, S1.CUSTOMER, S1.ID_CUSTOMER_CATEGORY, S1.CUSTOMER_CATEGORY, S1.SUPPLIER, S1.ID_PRODUCT_CATEGORY, S1.PRODUCT_CATEGORY, S1.YEAR, S1.MONTH, S1.AMOUNT AS CURRENT_YEAR, S2.AMOUNT AS PREVIOUS_YEAR, S1.AMOUNT - S2.AMOUNT AS DIFFERENCE
FROM 
    (SELECT * FROM V_YEAR_SALES) AS S1 
    LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT * FROM V_YEAR_SALES) AS S2 
        ON (S1.ID_ZONE = S2.ID_ZONE) 
        AND (S1.SUPPLIER = S2.SUPPLIER) 
        AND (S1.ID_PRODUCT_CATEGORY = S2.ID_PRODUCT_CATEGORY) 
        AND (S1.ID_CUSTOMER_CATEGORY = S2.ID_CUSTOMER_CATEGORY) 
        AND (S1.ID_CUSTOMER = S2.ID_CUSTOMER) 
        AND (S1.YEAR = S2.YEAR + 1) 
        AND (S1.MONTH = S2.MONTH);
```

In reference to the above **desired results table**, with this view I can obtain only the rows for customer A, B, D **but not C**!

**I need to include those customers of 2014 that didn't yet purchased in 2015!**

I'm using JOIN but I don't know if it is the best approach. Maybe I can use PIVOTING but I don't know if and how can be implemented with Access.

Comment: I feel like it's because of this line: `AND (S1.YEAR = S2.YEAR + 1) `.. Try making an `OR (S1.YEAR = S2.YEAR)` as well..? This is just a shot in the dark

Comment: @Invent-Animate: No, that way I only obtain many duplicate rows for each year/month/order with: [PREVIOUS_YEAR] = 100€ (or so), [CURRENT_YEAR] = 100€ (or so), [DIFFERENCE] = 0€.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution using **PIVOTING**.

The **V_YEAR_SALES** view was replaced with this:

```
TRANSFORM
IIF(SUM(O.AMOUNT) IS NULL, 0, SUM(O.AMOUNT))
SELECT Z.ID AS ID_ZONE, Z.CITY, C.COMPANY_NAME AS CUSTOMER, CAT.DESCRIPTION AS CUSTOMER_CATEGORY, P.SUPPLIER, P.DESCRIPTION AS PRODUCT_CATEGORY, I.MONTH, I.YEAR
FROM ((((ORDERS AS O 
    INNER JOIN CUSTOMERS AS C ON O.ID_CUSTOMER = C.ID) 
    INNER JOIN ZONES AS Z ON Z.ID = C.ID_ZONE) 
    INNER JOIN IMPORTS AS I ON I.ID = O.ID_IMPORT) 
    INNER JOIN CUSTOMER_CATEGORIES AS CAT ON CAT.ID = C.ID_CUSTOMER_CATEGORY)
    INNER JOIN PRODUCT_CATEGORIES AS P ON O.ID_PRODUCT_CATEGORY = P.ID
WHERE I.YEAR BETWEEN 
    (SELECT MAX(YEAR) FROM IMPORTS) AND (SELECT MAX(YEAR)-3 FROM IMPORTS)
GROUP BY Z.ID, Z.CITY, C.COMPANY_NAME, CAT.DESCRIPTION, P.SUPPLIER, P.DESCRIPTION, I.MONTH, I.YEAR
```

The `V_SALES_COMPARISON` view was deleted because is no more needed. My query now works only with `V_YEAR_SALES`.

Query the new `V_YEAR_SALES` is also **faster** than `V_SALES_COMPARISON`.

If you need to query the view from Access or without parameters:

```
SELECT S.*
FROM V_YEAR_SALES AS S
WHERE S.YEAR IN (2015, 2014) AND S.MONTH BETWEEN 1 AND 12;
```

Instead, if you need to query the view from code using Jet Driver and you also want to use parameters, you need to do like this:

```
PARAMETERS P0 TEXT(255), P1 TEXT(255), P2 TEXT(255), P3 TEXT(255);
SELECT S.*
FROM V_YEAR_SALES AS S
WHERE S.YEAR IN (@P0, @P1) AND S.MONTH BETWEEN @P2 AND @P3;
```

**Be CAREFUL** to include the `PARAMETERS` declaration (with also `;` before `SELECT` statement), otherwise you get error from Jet Driver:

```
The Microsoft Jet database engine does not recognize '[P0]' as a valid field name or expression.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go like this:

```
SELECT 
    Customer, 
    Sum(IIf(DateDiff("yyyy",[InvoiceDate],Date())=1,[Amount],0)) AS LastYear, 
    Sum(IIf(DateDiff("yyyy",[InvoiceDate],Date())=0,[Amount],0)) AS ThisYear, 
    Sum(IIf(DateDiff("yyyy",[InvoiceDate],Date())=0,[Amount],0)) 
       - Sum(IIf(DateDiff("yyyy",[InvoiceDate],Date())=1,[Amount],0)) AS Diff
FROM 
    Invoices
GROUP BY 
    Customer;
```

I see you have a separate year field, so try this method:

```
SELECT 
    Customer, 
    Sum(IIf(Year(Date())-[YearField]=1,[Amount],0)) AS LastYear, 
    Sum(IIf(Year(Date())-[YearField]=0,[Amount],0)) AS ThisYear, 
    Sum(IIf(Year(Date())-[YearField]=0,[Amount],0)) 
       - Sum(IIf(Year(Date())-[YearField]=1,[Amount],0)) AS Diff
FROM 
    Invoices
GROUP BY 
    Customer;
```

Comment: I tried to implement your code with my tables but I get only a list of customers with 0€ for each SUM column. Can you please make a working query with my tables or explain with more details you example?

Comment: See the revised code. It sums the amounts for the years that match.

Comment: No difference, always 0€ for each column. Anyway I need a query based on all the data that I have to join togheter.

Comment: Then something else is going on, or your data are different from your description. The code is tested and verfied here.

Comment: I don't use the `date` field of `ORDERS` table to get the year. Instead I need to use `year` and `month` fields from `IMPORTS` table. So I need at least one `JOIN` operation between `ORDERS` and `IMPORTS`. Then the `company_name` (or customer) field have to be taken from`CUSTOMERS` table and again another `JOIN` is needed. So taking your code "AS-IS" can't work with my tables and then I had to rearrange it. But I got no results.

Comment: Well, I don't have your tables. The last SQL used the year field. One option would be to create a straight select query with your joins returning just the fields you need. Then use this as source in a second query which could be modelled directly from my example.

Comment: The table structures are described in the question. There're of course no data... but the E-R diagram shows relations.